# Many PostgreSQL processes in Task Manager

Tags: postgresql, iis-8

We have a Windows Server 2012 with PostgreSQL 9.1 32-bit installed and Task Manager displays several "processes" with the name of "PostgreSQL Server (32 bit)" which eat a lot of CPU (99% sometimes). After some time, such PostgreSQL processes show 0% in the CPU usage with some memory occupied, but they remain in Task Manager.

What does it exactly mean?

The server runs a website (on IIS 8) and visitors connect to get (SELECT) data mainly. A few users (3 admin users) connect to the DB to perform all CRUD operations.

Best regards,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: tbh this is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow. Not only does it have nothing to do with programming, but it shows zero research effort.

Comment: See also in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/connect-estab.html  and this http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql02.html

Comment: 9.1 is no longer [supported and maintained](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should plan your upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 10 or 9.6) now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgresql fork his main process everytime a connection occurs. It is why you can get a lot of postgresql processes.

Now depending on queries that are running on those connections, it can use a lot of CPU and/or memory.

I guess you are also using a pool in your application, that means when a user finish his process, the connection goes back to the pool and the postgresql process will do nothing until the pool kill the connection or the connection is reused by another user.

If you enable some logs (connection logs, query logs if response time > some amount, temporary file usage, lock, ...), you can later run a report like pgbadger ([example here](http://pgbadger.darold.net/samplev7.html)) to check if there is queries that are too slow or use too much memory (worst: temporary file)